# CSS clip-path works in Firefox, but not in chrome

Tags: html, css, svg, cross-browser

While working on a new project, I encountered a weird issue I simply can't fix.
I am using 5 DIVs, each with their own SVG clip-path. While this works fine in Firefox (1st screenshot), the masks aren't applied in Chrome (not even mentioning Internet Explorer). 
[image]
Here's the part of the HTML responsible for creating the DIVs. The two "_sep" divs are the white lines you can see between the other three main DIVs.

```
<div class="main bg">

    <div id="left" class="index_clip">
        <img src="includes/img/main/parts.png">
    </div>

    <div id="left_sep" class="index_clip">

    </div>
    <div id="mid" class="index_clip">
        <img src="includes/img/main/werkstatt.png">
    </div>

    <div id="center_sep" class="index_clip">

    </div>

    <div id="right" class="index_clip">
        <img src="includes/img/main/suspension.png">
    </div>
    <!-- <img id="overlay" src="includes/img/main/overlay.png"> -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.index_clip{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#left{
    -webkit-clip-path: url('../svg/svg.svg#left_clip');
    clip-path: url('../svg/svg.svg#left_clip');
    z-index: 2;
}
#left img{
    top: 50%;
    left: 7%;
    transform:translate(0px, -50%);
}
#left_sep{
    -webkit-clip-path: url('../svg/svg.svg#left_sep_clip');
    clip-path: url('../svg/svg.svg#left_sep_clip');
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: white;
}

#mid{
    z-index: 1;
        -webkit-clip-path: url('../svg/svg.svg#center_clip');
        clip-path: url('../svg/svg.svg#center_clip');
}
#mid img{
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
#center_sep{
    -webkit-clip-path: url('../svg/svg.svg#center_sep_clip');
    clip-path: url('../svg/svg.svg#center_sep_clip');
    background-color: white;
}
#right{
    -webkit-clip-path: url('../svg/svg.svg#right_clip');
    clip-path: url('../svg/svg.svg#right_clip');
    z-index: 1;
    /*background-color: blue;   */
}

#right img{
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0px,-50%);
    left: 82%;
}
```

I already found out that Chrome uses the wrong relative path. It seems, as if Chrome interprets "url('../svg/svg.svg#left_sep_clip')" from the location of the index.php file, not the CSS file. I already tried using absolute URLs, but it still doesn't work in Chrome. What is the reason for it not working in Chrome? How can I fix the issue? You can try a live example [here](https://www.designwise.at/wcp_new/index.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome does not support shapes using SVGs from external SVGs.

http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Comment: Wow, I already checked that but apparently skipped the last sentence... Copying the <defs> from the SVG-File into a SVG-tag in the index.php and changing the url in the CSS file fixes the issue. Now it works perfectly, but for whatever reason it also worked after copying the defs **without** changing anything in the CSS file...